# Scripting for After Effect

Tags: html, script, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to make a simple script for After  effects, i HAVE A GOOD KNOWLEDGE WITH java Script,css and html
I have used brackets and Adobe Extend script tools 
but I think I need to arrange the steps that will help me